# mysql select ID where date is current date

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table structure:

**Rows**

```
ID |  Counter  |  Dates
```

**Values**

```
1  |  100;300;44 |  01.01.2016;02.11.2016;03.03.2017
```

each ID is connected to an separated user.
at the moment i have 100 users, so 100 data in my table.
now i need an sql command, which show me the the ID from the user, which have a date in the Dates-Row, which is the same like the current date

Comment: Normalize your table, one row per record. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: if i will do this like your way: would be the request time not to long? it can be  thousand of rows

Comment: MySQL can handle millions of rows in no time... (given proper indexes)

Comment: No. Databases are designed exactly for that purpose. If you put an index on the column(s) you often search for, e.g. on the date columns, then a query with even millions of records won't take longer than a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Dates LIKE CONCAT('%',DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m.%d.%Y'),'%');
```

This will select the current date `CURDATE()`, put it in the format you use in your table, then stick wildcards on each end so it will look inside of the string within your Dates column.